# UnsatisfiedLinkError (Native method not found)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

There is a block of code which is working fine on android 4.1.2 but not on 4.0.3, the crash log is of 4.0.3

I am getting UnsatisfiedLinkError Exception

**Please guide me thanks**

```
02-22 12:57:09.319: D/dalvikvm(1312): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.kosh.android/lib/libsqliteX.so 0x41056f48
02-22 12:57:09.319: D/dalvikvm(1312): Added shared lib /data/data/com.kosh.android/lib/libsqliteX.so 0x41056f48
02-22 12:58:02.060: W/dalvikvm(1312): No implementation found for native Lcom/shabdkosh/android/sqlite/CursorWindow;.native_init (Z)V
02-22 12:58:07.624: D/AndroidRuntime(1312): Shutting down VM
02-22 12:58:07.624: W/dalvikvm(1312): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: native_init
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.kosh.android.sqlite.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.kosh.android.sqlite.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:35)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.awc_clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:150)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:125)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:158)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:235)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.kosh.android.offline.Handler.newdb1_index0_list(Handler.java:99)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.kosh.android.offline.SearchDataDB.getAutoSuggestion(SearchDataDB.java:29)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.kosh.android.MainActivity.onQueryTextChange(MainActivity.java:885)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1081)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.SearchView.access$1900(SearchView.java:90)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.SearchView$10.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1536)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7577)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7617)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:7990)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:881)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:266)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:443)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:420)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:29)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:218)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:132)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5386)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5206)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:682)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2533)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:5446)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1248)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1859)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3273)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-22 12:58:07.767: E/AndroidRuntime(1312):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**HERE IS MY CLASS**

```
package com.kosh.android.sqlite;

import android.database.CharArrayBuffer;

import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
* A buffer containing multiple cursor rows.
*/
public class CursorWindow extends android.database.CursorWindow implements Parcelable {
/** The pointer to the native window class */


/** The pointer to the native window class. set by the native methods in
 * android_database_CursorWindow.cpp
 */
private int nWindow;
private int mStartPos;
/**
 * Creates a new empty window.
 *
 * @param localWindow true if this window will be used in this process only
 */

public CursorWindow(boolean localWindow) {
    super(localWindow);
    mStartPos = 0;
    native_init(localWindow);
}

/**
 * Returns the starting position of this window within the entire
 * Cursor's result set.
 *
 * @return the starting position of this window within the entire
 * Cursor's result set.
 */
public int getStartPosition() {
    return mStartPos;
}

/**
 * Set the start position of cursor window
 * @param pos
 */
public void setStartPosition(int pos) {
    mStartPos = pos;
}    

/**
 * Returns the number of rows in this window.
 * 
 * @return the number of rows in this window.
 */
public int getNumRows() {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getNumRows_native();
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native int getNumRows_native();
/**
 * Set number of Columns 
 * @param columnNum
 * @return true if success
 */
public boolean setNumColumns(int columnNum) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return setNumColumns_native(columnNum);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean setNumColumns_native(int columnNum);

/**
 * Allocate a row in cursor window
 * @return false if cursor window is out of memory
 */
public boolean allocRow(){
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return allocRow_native();
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean allocRow_native();    

/**
 * Free the last row
 */
public void freeLastRow(){
    acquireReference();
    try {
        freeLastRow_native();
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native void freeLastRow_native();

/**
 * copy byte array to cursor window
 * @param value
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return false if fail to copy
 */
public boolean putBlob(byte[] value, int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return putBlob_native(value, row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean putBlob_native(byte[] value, int row, int col);    

/**
 * Copy String to cursor window
 * @param value
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return false if fail to copy
 */
public boolean putString(String value, int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return putString_native(value, row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean putString_native(String value, int row, int col);    

/**
 * Copy integer to cursor window
 * @param value
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return false if fail to copy
 */
public boolean putLong(long value, int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return putLong_native(value, row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean putLong_native(long value, int row, int col);


/**
 * Copy double to cursor window 
 * @param value
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return false if fail to copy
 */
public boolean putDouble(double value, int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return putDouble_native(value, row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean putDouble_native(double value, int row, int col);    

/**
 * Set the [row, col] value to NULL
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return false if fail to copy
 */
public boolean putNull(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return putNull_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean putNull_native(int row, int col);


/**
 * Returns {@code true} if given field is {@code NULL}.
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return {@code true} if given field is {@code NULL}
 */
public boolean isNull(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return isNull_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean isNull_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * Returns a byte array for the given field.
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a String value for the given field
 */
public byte[] getBlob(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getBlob_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the value at (<code>row</code>, <code>col</code>) as a <code>byte</code> array.
 *
 * <p>If the value is null, then <code>null</code> is returned. If the
 * type of column <code>col</code> is a string type, then the result
 * is the array of bytes that make up the internal representation of the
 * string value. If the type of column <code>col</code> is integral or floating-point,
 * then an {@link SQLiteException} is thrown.
 */
private native byte[] getBlob_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * Returns data type of the given column's value.
 *<p>
 * Returned column types are
 * <ul>
 *   <li>{@link Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_NULL}</li>
 *   <li>{@link Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER}</li>
 *   <li>{@link Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT}</li>
 *   <li>{@link Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_STRING}</li>
 *   <li>{@link Cursor#FIELD_TYPE_BLOB}</li>
 *</ul>
 *</p>
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return the value type
 */
public int getType(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getType_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if a field contains either a blob or is null.
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return {@code true} if given field is {@code NULL} or a blob
 * @deprecated use {@link #getType(int, int)} instead
 */
public boolean isBlob(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return isBlob_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if a field contains a long
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return {@code true} if given field is a long
 * @deprecated use {@link #getType(int, int)} instead
 */
public boolean isLong(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return isInteger_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if a field contains a float.
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return {@code true} if given field is a float
 * @deprecated use {@link #getType(int, int)} instead
 */
public boolean isFloat(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return isFloat_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if a field contains either a String or is null.
 *
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return {@code true} if given field is {@code NULL} or a String
 * @deprecated use {@link #getType(int, int)} instead
 */
public boolean isString(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return isString_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native boolean isBlob_native(int row, int col);
private native boolean isString_native(int row, int col);
private native boolean isInteger_native(int row, int col);
private native boolean isFloat_native(int row, int col);

private native int getType_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * Returns a String for the given field.
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a String value for the given field
 */
public String getString(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getString_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the value at (<code>row</code>, <code>col</code>) as a <code>String</code>.
 *
 * <p>If the value is null, then <code>null</code> is returned. If the
 * type of column <code>col</code> is integral, then the result is the string
 * that is obtained by formatting the integer value with the <code>printf</code>
 * family of functions using format specifier <code>%lld</code>. If the
 * type of column <code>col</code> is floating-point, then the result is the string
 * that is obtained by formatting the floating-point value with the
 * <code>printf</code> family of functions using format specifier <code>%g</code>.
 * If the type of column <code>col</code> is a blob type, then an
 * {@link SQLiteException} is thrown.
 */
private native String getString_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * copy the text for the given field in the provided char array.
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @param buffer the CharArrayBuffer to copy the text into,      
 * If the requested string is larger than the buffer 
 * a new char buffer will be created to hold the string. and assigne to
 * CharArrayBuffer.data
  */
public void copyStringToBuffer(int row, int col, CharArrayBuffer buffer) {
    if (buffer == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("CharArrayBuffer should not be null");
    }
    if (buffer.data == null) {
        buffer.data = new char[64];
    }
    acquireReference();
    try {
        char[] newbuf = copyStringToBuffer_native(
                row - mStartPos, col, buffer.data.length, buffer);
        if (newbuf != null) {
            buffer.data = newbuf;
        }
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

private native char[] copyStringToBuffer_native(
        int row, int col, int bufferSize, CharArrayBuffer buffer);

/**
 * Returns a long for the given field.
 * row is 0 based
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a long value for the given field
 */
public long getLong(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getLong_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the value at (<code>row</code>, <code>col</code>) as a <code>long</code>.
 *
 * <p>If the value is null, then <code>0L</code> is returned. If the
 * type of column <code>col</code> is a string type, then the result
 * is the <code>long</code> that is obtained by parsing the string value with
 * <code>strtoll</code>. If the type of column <code>col</code> is
 * floating-point, then the result is the floating-point value casted to a <code>long</code>.
 * If the type of column <code>col</code> is a blob type, then an
 * {@link SQLiteException} is thrown.
 */
private native long getLong_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * Returns a double for the given field.
 * row is 0 based
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a double value for the given field
 */
public double getDouble(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return getDouble_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the value at (<code>row</code>, <code>col</code>) as a <code>double</code>.
 *
 * <p>If the value is null, then <code>0.0</code> is returned. If the
 * type of column <code>col</code> is a string type, then the result
 * is the <code>double</code> that is obtained by parsing the string value with
 * <code>strtod</code>. If the type of column <code>col</code> is
 * integral, then the result is the integer value casted to a <code>double</code>.
 * If the type of column <code>col</code> is a blob type, then an
 * {@link SQLiteException} is thrown.
 */
private native double getDouble_native(int row, int col);

/**
 * Returns a short for the given field.
 * row is 0 based
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a short value for the given field
 */
public short getShort(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return (short) getLong_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns an int for the given field.
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return an int value for the given field
 */
public int getInt(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return (int) getLong_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a float for the given field.
 * row is 0 based
 * 
 * @param row the row to read from, row - getStartPosition() being the actual row in the window 
 * @param col the column to read from
 * @return a float value for the given field
 */
public float getFloat(int row, int col) {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        return (float) getDouble_native(row - mStartPos, col);
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
} 

/**
 * Clears out the existing contents of the window, making it safe to reuse
 * for new data. Note that the number of columns in the window may NOT
 * change across a call to clear().
 */
public void clear() {
    acquireReference();
    try {
        mStartPos = 0;        
        native_clear();
    } finally {
        releaseReference();
    }
}

/** Clears out the native side of things */
private native void native_clear();

/**
 * Cleans up the native resources associated with the window.
 */
public void close() {
    releaseReference();
}

private native void close_native();

@Override
protected void finalize() {
    // Just in case someone forgot to call close...
    if (nWindow == 0) {
        return;
    }
    close_native();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<CursorWindow> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<CursorWindow>() {
    public CursorWindow createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new CursorWindow(source,0);
    }

    public CursorWindow[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CursorWindow[size];
    }
};

public static CursorWindow newFromParcel(Parcel p) {
    return CREATOR.createFromParcel(p);
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStrongBinder(native_getBinder());
    dest.writeInt(mStartPos);
}


public CursorWindow(Parcel source,int foo) {

    super(true);

    IBinder nativeBinder = source.readStrongBinder();
    mStartPos = source.readInt();

    native_init(nativeBinder);
}

/** Get the binder for the native side of the window */
private native IBinder native_getBinder();

/** Does the native side initialization for an empty window */
private native void native_init(boolean localOnly);

/** Does the native side initialization with an existing binder from another process */
private native void native_init(IBinder nativeBinder);

@Override
protected void onAllReferencesReleased() {
    close_native();

    super.onAllReferencesReleased();
}
}
```

Here is the source cpp files from where i have compiled and created the binary "libsqliteX.so" file http://www.sqlite.org/android/tree?ci=trunk&re=jni|src/org/sqlite/data&expand

my .so file https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0u5pyhke54tcd6/libsqliteX.so

Here is CDT GLOBAL BUILD CONSOLE

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project CustomSqlite ****

D:\software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteGlobal.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteDebug.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= JNIHelp.cpp
"Compile++ thumb : sqliteX <= JniConstants.cpp
"Compile thumb : sqliteX <= sqlite3.c
SharedLibrary  : libsqliteX.so
Install        : libsqliteX.so => libs/armeabi/libsqliteX.so

**** Build Finished ****

**** Build of configuration Default for project CustomSqlite ****

D:\software\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\android-ndk-r9-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd all 
Install        : libsqliteX.so => libs/armeabi/libsqliteX.so

**** Build Finished ****
```

This line creates the problem

```
native_init(localWindow);
```

pls consider this

What/where i m doing wrong and how to overcome this problem i am stuck with this from 3 days

Thanks

Comment: Edit the question with the C declararions/definitions (H and C). Drop unrelated Java code (the not native parts)

Comment: @manuell This project is working fine on android 4.1.2 but not on 4.0.3, the crash log is of 4.0.3 only Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that the runtime tried to find a matching method but was unsuccessful. Some common reasons for this are:

- The library isn't getting loaded. Check the logcat output for messages about library loading.
- The method isn't being found due to a name or signature mismatch.

This is an error that happens quite [often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096355/no-implementation-found-for-native). You can find more details about it on:

- [Why do I get UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html)

Whenever doing native code for cross-platform, any detail missing from your [toolchain](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4455/no-implementation-found-error-in-opencv-android/) will make your application to crash.