# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am working with CsipSimple and try to create an account in local network...the build runs fine....but i can't make my account active....at the beginning of the project run it catches an exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.......and it says unable to load native library...I have been searching all day long...i created armeabi-v7a under lib folder....and I have downloaded two .so file from firefox nightly build as descripted in this link.... [here](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) but i have same problem....please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a native for which an implementation could not be found. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html

Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22121375/1761003

Please do post some code for better reply