# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no IBScanUltimate in java.library.path

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no IBScanUltimate in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.integratedbiometrics.ibscanultimate.IBScan.<clinit>(IBScan.java:574)
    at com.sample.functiontester.FunctionTester.<init>(FunctionTester.java:604)
    at com.sample.functiontester.FunctionTester.main(FunctionTester.java:76)
```

The project is working on another machine, but when I try to pull it out of this error

Comment: JAR containing `IBScanUltimate` is present on one machine but not on another. Or (if you do not build JARs) the same would apply to class file.

Comment: IBScanUltimate is some kind of native system library (DLL, .so). Check if this lib exists on your system within the PATH (windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (linux).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsatisfiedLinkError (Native method not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872804/unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method-not-found)